# Cost-sensitive SVM with sklearn

Tags: svm, skewness, loss-functions

Is there a direct cost-sensitive implementation of the SVM classifiers (CS-SVM) within the sklearn module? There are several ad hoc methods for the cost-sensitive SVM on "the market", but I am wondering whether there is a simple way to integrate a CS-SVM into a python pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's a `class_weight` parameter in sklearn's svm, you can put a dictionary that specifies the weights of different classes.

there's an example page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html

Comment: Hi, the function of `class_weight` parameters is to tackle the class imbalance problem, and there is a library available here: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn